# How to use newly defined delegated property in a Gradle build in Kotlin 1.4 without a NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

Gradle 6.6.1 seems to force the 1.3.72 version of the stdlib no matter what, which means new methods added for properties in 1.4 don't work. Oddly enough, the lazy property does work.
If I simply create a new Gradle project, add in a simple buildSrc with a build.gradle like so:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And I define and use a delegated property in the buildSrc like so:

```
class TestPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(p0: Project) {
        val x by Delegate()
    }
}
class Delegate {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) {
    }
}
```

And apply the plugin in the top level project: `apply plugin: TestPlugin`, I get warnings regarding both the 1.3.72 version of the stdlib and the 1.4 version being on the classpath, and this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.jvm.internal.PropertyReference0Impl.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at TestPlugin.<clinit>(TestPlugin.kt)
```

I've tried doing this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'org.jetbrains.kotlin') {
            details.useVersion '1.4.0'
        }
    }
}
```

But that did not help. So I can make sure Gradle uses Kotlin 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot change the Gradle runtime to use Kotlin 1.4.0. One strong reason for this is that Gradle (6.6) has been tested as a whole with Kotlin 1.3.72, and it could lead to unforeseeable internal failures if you were to replace the runtime. Gradle will eventually bundle Kotlin 1.4.0 (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12660).